# How do I know if I am running Wubi or a proper dual-boot?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I tried to setup a "proper" Windows/Ubuntu dual-boot system, by installing Ubuntu from a USB key. However, I simply could not get the laptop to boot off the USB despite the fact that I made the appropriate changes to the boot device order in the BIOS.

So I then turned to Wubi, and (to cut a long story short) it seems I now have a proper dual-boot setup, because I don't need to launch Ubuntu from windows. When I start the laptop, I get that screen that asks me whether I want to run Windows or Ubuntu.

However, I'm still not sure if this is a proper dual-boot setup, because when I run windows, it seems that my C: and D: drives are still the same size. If it was a proper dual boot I'd expect separate partitions to have been created for Ubuntu which would have removed some space from the C: and D: drive sizes displayed in Windows.

Is there some way that I can confirm whether I'm running a proper dual-boot, and if not, is there some process for converting a Wubi installation to a proper dual-boot?

Comment: If you think this question has been answered correctly, consider marking the answer with a green tick mark and indicate that it is correct. This will help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Both Wubi and "dual boot" allows you to choose Windows or Ubuntu when you start the computer. However, Wubi uses a virtual partition in a big file inside Windows partition to store the Ubuntu installation and all the user data.

**In windows**

Boot into Windows and look for the file `c:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` (or it may be in D:). If you find it, you have installed using Wubi.

**Alternately in Ubuntu**

Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and enter:

```
sudo losetup /dev/loop0
```

and if that says `/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` you know it's Wubi. (Thanks @bcbc)

There is a [script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi) to move Wubi installation to its own partition and thus make it a true dual boot. However, this is a bit complicated and you may be better off doing a fresh install from a CD or USB after uninstalling the Wubi installation from within Windows.

In either case, backup all the data first.

Comment: If you find a file `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` then it tells you that you have a file called `\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` (there could be something leftover from a previous install). What you want is `sudo losetup /dev/loop0` and if that says `/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` you know it's Wubi.